# Cannot Compile C++ in Cython on Windows 10

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-c++, cython

I have been trying to follow the tutorial here for using C++ with Cython:

http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class

However, I am running into issues.  Here is the setup of my files:

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace shapes;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1){
    x0 = X0;
    y0 = Y0;
    x1 = X1;
    y1 = Y1;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}

int Rectangle::getLength() {
    return (x1 - x0);
}

int Rectangle::getHeight() {
    return (y1 - y0);
} 

int Rectangle::getArea() {
    return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
}

void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
    x0 += dx;
    y0 += dy;
    x1 += dx;
    y1 += dy;
}
```

**Rectangle.h**

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
    ~Rectangle();
    int getLength();
    int getHeight();
    int getArea();
    void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
 }
```

**rectangle.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int)
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getLength()
        int getHeight()
        int getArea()
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rectangle.pyx",            # our Cython source
       sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

However, if I try to run `python setup.py build_ext`, I get the following output:

```
PS D:\Projects\Examples\Python\Cython\c++> python setup.py build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    language="c++",             # generate C++ code
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 886, in cythonize
    c_options = CompilationOptions(**options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 565, in __init__
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: got unknown compilation option, please remove: sources
```

If I cannot specify the 'sources', I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing instead.  **Does anybody understand what I'm doing wrong?**

Here's my system info:

```
Windows 10 build 14393
Cython==0.28.5
Python 3.7.0
```

Comment: Seems like this project had the same issue you had, you can try to apply the patch: https://github.com/jmnybl/setlib/pull/1/files

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts, I tried that, but now I just receive this error message instead: https://pastebin.com/NxCAKHGq
This time, it's reporting "setup_requires" as an invalid option.  I'm just so lost, I don't understand why it's so difficult to use C++ and Cython together on Windows.